# Fetch specific returned row information in PDO

Tags: php, pdo, record, fetch

I have a table stores logins information such as date, time, etc. Whenever a user signs into my website, I store these information on the table. Also I would like to tell him when was his previous login, so I need to show last second row information to him.
How can I do it in PDO? I wrote this code, but it returns last record, not what I need.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT date,hour FROM tbl_logins WHERE uid = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$q = $db->prepare($sql2);
$q->execute(array($_SESSION['uid']));
$r = $q->fetch();
$fdate = $r['date'];
$hour = $r['hour'];
```

Comment: please give some example data u store in tbl_logins for a user..

Comment: @Enam it's clear. User ID, login time, login date

Comment: u need to retrieve the last log in info before u store the current log in info..with out changing current code or u need to modify little bit ur code. thx

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = $q->fetch();
```

Should only be returning one row. My guess? Your SESSION var isn't correct or you've got an error in your SQL. What mode is PDO running in? Exceptions? Default?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: after confirm the login, retrieve the last login info:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT fdate,hour FROM tbl_logins WHERE uid = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$q = $db->prepare($sql2);
$q->execute(array($_SESSION['uid']));
$r = $q->fetch();
$fdate = $r['fdate'];
$hour = $r['hour'];
```

after that:

Run The update tbl_logins code to store current login date and time.